# Is using apache and nginx at the same time a good idea?

Tags: nginx, apache-2.4

I sometimes use apache in port 81 and run in port 80 (or 443) using nginx, like this

```
location / {
proxy_pass http://localhost:81
}
```

I have to do this because some software (Like phpbb does not run properly on nginx)
Is this a good idea?

Comment: You can certainly serve phpBB with nginx.

Comment: >You can certainly serve phpBB with nginx i got errors and i'm to lazy to fix those errors

Comment: If you are too lazy to fix the issues then you should not ask whether it's a good idea to run both Apache and nginx. Would you fix the issues if we told you it was a bad idea or would you only shrug at our reply and still be doing it because "you're too lazy to fix the issues"?

Comment: my question wasn't about how to fix phpbb. please read the title

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is certainly nothing wrong with running a reverse proxy like this, but you do need to decide if it is really necessary.

If you can avoid doing so it will be easier all the way around. It shouldn't be your default. If there is some specific benefit you need - specific versions of libraries, proxying back to a different network segment, etc - it's worth while.

Answer (score 3):

Nginx has capability to cache and deliver static content very fast (in comparsion to apache), so combination of both servers in some cases works well.
If you use nginx as a proxy to Apache, you can tune Apache to listen only on loopback address (127.0.0.1) not to confuse if someone will come to your host at port 81.
And, sure, phpbb works perfectly with nginx only. Better describe your problem, what is not properly in your meaning?